# How to get db field from class object

Tags: laravel, object, model

I execute this update statement which works fine.

```
$g = Group::where([['id', $idgroup], ['admin', $currentUser]]);
$g->update(['admin' => $iduser]);
```

After this statement I need the field name from my Group object. But with the following statement I get Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$name.

```
$groupname = $g->name;
```

Group is my model (DB table) which contains the field id, name, admin. How can I get the field name from this object?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without finder it will return you a query builder but when you need to fetch model instance then apply `get` (for [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) of model) or `first`(for single model instance) on query builder. For your case you need to call `first()` method like this

```
$g = Group::where([['id', $idgroup], ['admin', $currentUser]])->first();
$g->update(['admin' => $iduser]);
```

Then you can do

```
$groupname = $g->name;
```

You can check the details here for [retrieving model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: I get this error... Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
admin

Comment: You need to set which fields are mass assignable, meaning which one you can call update on them. Like this: protected $fillable = ['admin'];

Comment: @Flamms yes you need to add `$fillable = ['admin'];` in your `Group` model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one record from database then use `first()`:

```
$g = Group::where([['id', $idgroup], ['admin', $currentUser]])->first();

$g->name; //it will output name
```

OR
If you want to get all record from database then use `get()`:

```
$groups = Group::where([['id', $idgroup], ['admin', $currentUser]])->get();
```

To get name from here you will have to run loop because `get()` will return a collection

```
foreach($groups as $g){
   $g->name; //it will give name 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $g variable is a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder which represent a query, not a single object, which means it doesn't have the Group properties. It's very likely you have more than one record under $g, you have two options retrieve all the names fields like this

```
$g->pluck('name')
```

This will give you a collection of all the names, or if you're certain there's one single object, you can do $g->first()->name, it will give you the name of the first object (only one if you're sure there is only one object)